"There should be at least a factor of four between sample rate and upper edge of passband"
Publishing a paper within biomedical engineering, specifically concerning time series data, we have gotten into a disagreement with a reviewer. Specifically, the reviewer says that "the upper edge of a passband should be no higher than 25% of the sample rate".
Has anyone heard of this rule before, and if so, could you share a reason or a reference?
I have not heard this rule anywhere else. We tried showing the filter gain in our response, clearly demonstrating a significant drop between our upper edge and the Nyquist frequency, but the reviewer says that "The Nyquist frequency and its implications for harmonic signals do not directly translate to more intricate biological signals, which often exhibit non-linearities and various artifacts."
Can anyone elaborate what kind of worst-case scenario the reviewer is referring to? If the reviewer is right, I would like to learn why, and if not, it might be easier to demonstrate that our approach is fine if we could understand the problem.

There isn't a good theoretical reason.  Because of frequency warping using bilinear transform, there is a "scrunching" of the top octave, but you don't have to design filters using the bilinear transform.  Essentially, whoever wrote that was saying we should oversample by at least a factor of 2.

@robertbristow-johnson yeah, I agree, that's what s/he's saying. I'm just trying to understand why this person thinks that this is the standard approach. Looking at the sampling theorem in my closest  DSP textbook, I found no reference to assumptions of harmonic or 'linear' signals.


"The Nyquist frequency and its implications for harmonic signals do not directly translate to more intricate biological signals, which often exhibit non-linearities and various artifacts."

That sounds problematic to me. First of all the "Nyquist frequency and its implications" apply to all signals, harmonic, biological, intricate or otherwise. Secondly non-linearity is a property of a system, not a signal. There is no such thing as a "non-linear" signal. Thirdly, "various artifacts" is  sloppy language (at best) and doesn't mean anything unless properly defined.
This being said, it's quite common to operate at a higher sample rate if you do non-linear processing. Non-linear processing will increase the bandwidth of the signal which leads to aliasing. But even in this case  the "25%" rule seems overly simplistic and the correct choice depends on the nature of the non-linearities and the actual signal.

I had a tour of all the signal processing experts in the department today. The best anyone could come up with was if the reviewer was confusing analog and digital filtering, in which case, yes, added caution when designing an analog anti-aliasing filter inside an ADC might be appropriate. But that is not what's going on, and no one could come up with a case where the Shannon-Nyquist sampling theorem would not apply for a digital signal that wasn't being resampled.

The fact that Reviewer #2 is referring to "nonlinear signals" means that they're not strong in signal processing.  I've learned, however, that just because someone doesn't know the lingo or the details of the math, that doesn't mean that they're wrong.
There's a strong chance that there's some validity to their rule of thumb, however.  In signal processing language "more intricate biological signals, which often exhibit non-linearities and various artifacts" probably translates to "you are looking at signals which cannot be neatly defined in frequency-domain terms".
Applying any filter with a response steep enough that you can safely sample at 4 times the filter's nominal passband means that for impulsive signals, the filter is going to ring, and that ringing is going to distort any edges in your incoming signal.
Either your signal going into the filter is always slow enough that you could filter it with a much lower bandwidth, or it's got transitions that are fast enough that you're going to excite that ringing.  I think this is probably what Reviewer #2 knows from bitter experience, even if they offend signal processing purists by implicitly claiming that signals can be nonlinear.
I suggest that you test your filter not just by looking at its response in the frequency domain, but by feeding it some real signals and looking at its time domain response.  If you don't have real signals to feed it, and you know enough about what you're looking at, feed it something impulsive or with lots of edges and look at the time domain of that response.
Two simple "worst case" signals that I can think of are a step and a narrow pulse.  Hit the filter with a step input, and look at its output.  Then hit it with a pulse that's $\frac 1 {F_s}$ wide, or even narrower, where $F_s$ is your sampling rate.
Can your follow-on processing gracefully deal with either of these?

yeah, we have considered something like that, but then I get stuck at what kind of test this person would actually be satisfied with. We have plenty of real data to feed the filter, and could very easily compare the waveforms before and after filtering, but if the reviewer just thinks we focused on a piece of 'nice' data, that doesn't get us anywhere. Hence, I was wondering if anyone had some input for how to create such a 'worst case' scenario, which the person would accept as an honest test.

I edited in some simple -- but potentially convincing -- examples.
